# Looking for workaround to successfully convert PDType0Font and PDType1Fonts with pdf2dom

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox, pdf-to-html

We are using [pdf2dom](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/pdf2dom/) library to convert a large set of newspaper pdfs to html. Number of pdfs in question exceed 5k pdf pages per day.

Although we succeed in majority of cases and scenarios we fail to convert the pdfs fully in most cases. and get the following types of errors -

> Font: Helvetica skipped because type 'PDType1Font' is not supported.

and

> Could not find character code for glyph name. Name:'fraction'
>   GlyphID:'217' Could not find character code for glyph name. Name:'fi'
>   GlyphID:'218' Could not find character code for glyph name. Name:'fl'
>   GlyphID:'219' Could not find character code for glyph name.
>   Name:'breve' GlyphID:'220' Could not find character code for glyph
>   name. Name:'dotaccent' GlyphID:'221' Could not find character code for
>   glyph name. Name:'ring' GlyphID:'222'

and

> Issue converting Bare CFF font or the font type is not supportedby
>   Pdf2Dom, Font: UniversLTStd-Bold Exception: Index: 0, Size: 0 class
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

and

> Font: RXKFZF+*Calibri-Bold skipped because type 'PDType0Font' is not
>   supported.

Since our goal is to convert the pdf to html with complete text and appropropriate format information i.e. size / bold / italic etc. and we can ignore the font, we are looking for an effective way to transform / replace the unsupported Type 1 and Type 0 fonts with equivalent fonts.

Any workarounds and pointers would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I added the two libraries that seem to provide workarounds i.e. Fontverter and jbrotli as described in this article on dzone  - https://dzone.com/articles/things-i-learned-about-fonts-while-making-a-java-font-library, still no luck :(

Comment: Pdfbox extractText command line utility can convert to html but I guess that isn't what you want?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr correct. I need the fully converted HTML and not the plain text. So I am using pdf2dom and not pdfbox directly. the issues listed above are of pdf2dom library and as of now I believe all can have workarounds but don't know how. This question is to find these solutions.

Comment: My recommendation is that you make the needed code changes yourself. Type1 fonts are nicely implemented in PDFBox 2.0.* fontbox, so whatever information is needed in pdf2dom should be accessed or copied from fontbox. Type 0 fonts are more tricky but if you've succeeded with type1 fonts it should be easier.

Comment: If you can provide (1) some code snippet how you use pdf2dom and (2) one example PDF, the "community" might be able to help you more. Both are open source projects so its possible...